# EF Core 3.1 Query results in an InvalidOperationException Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid

Tags: .net-core, ef-core-3.1

Why does this EF Core 3.1 typical query result in:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Lambda expression used inside
> Include is not valid.

(Note: IgnoreQueryFilters() is not the issue here. Even without it, it results in the same error)

```
var tenant = await context.Tenants.IgnoreQueryFilters()
                .Include(i => i.Locations).ThenInclude(x => x.CurrentResidents.DefaultIfEmpty()).IgnoreQueryFilters()
                .Include(i => i.Locations).ThenInclude(x => x.DefaultResidents.DefaultIfEmpty()).IgnoreQueryFilters()
                .Where(l => l.Id == tenantId)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync()
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Here's my sql interpretation of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
select t.* from tenants
left join locations l on l.TenantId = t.Id
left join residents c on c.CurrentLocationId = l.Id
left join residents d on d.DefaultLocationId = l.Id
where t.Id = @tenantId
```

Please help. :pray:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was what I was looking for:

```
 var tenant = await context.Tenants
                .IgnoreQueryFilters()
                .Include(i => i.Locations).ThenInclude(x => x.CurrentResidents)
                .Include(i => i.Locations).ThenInclude(x => x.CurrentResidents)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(l => l.Id == tenantId)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Sql generated by ef core is a little weird but yields the result I'm interested in so all good.

@bencel: thank you for pointing out those issues. I was focused on getting the query running so overlooked those.

Thanks everyone!!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is including `Locations` twice. Not sure from your SQL what you are trying to retrieve. The residents for whom both `CurrentLocationId` *AND* `DefaultLocationId` matches `LocationId`? then use AND in the LINQ statement.
If something else, then what is the type of CurrentResidents and DefaultResidents? Same `Resident` type? Then you probably want to get two sets...
Please provide more information...

Answer (score 0):

As Felix pointed out the problem is that you include Locations twice which is not correct in ef core. Here is how you can achieve this:

```
var tenant = await context.Tenants
            .IgnoreQueryFilters()
            .Include(i => i.Locations.CurrentResidents.DefaultIfEmpty())
            .Include(i => i.Locations.DefaultResidents.DefaultIfEmpty())
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(l => l.Id == tenantId, cancellationToken)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Calling IgnoreQueryFilters once is sufficient, you don't need to call it 3 times.

Calling where and the first or default is unnecessary. You can just use the lambda in the first or default.